# Spring Boot/Spring Integration Servlet Context/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm not sure the best way to word this issue, because I have no idea why this happens.
When I start up my Spring Boot application without the spring-integration-core jar, my app starts up fine. The second I add the spring-boot-starter-integration or any spring-integration-core library to my Maven pom file the servlet context is always null on my `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` class and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
```

After doing some debugging, I see the `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` class initialized before the `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` sets the servlet context for my application, which makes sense why the servlet context is null for my `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` and set for all the other classes initialized with `postProcessBeforeInitialization` in `ServletContextAwareProcessor`. Simply removing the Spring Integration dependency fixes the issue, but I'd like to use Spring Integration in my Boot application.

My question is what would cause the `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` to be created before the `EmbeddedWebApplicationContext` can call `prepareEmbeddedWebApplicationContext` method.

Spring dependencies using Spring Boot 1.1.8.RELEASE:
        
            org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.16.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

My root configuration file:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   @EnableAsync
   @EnableEntityLinks
   @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
   @ComponentScan
   @PropertySource(value = "file:../application.properties",
        ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
   public class ApplicationInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer
        implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationInitializer.class, args);
      }

      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
         return application.sources(ApplicationInitializer.class);
      }

      @Override
      public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.setContextPath(APPLICATION_ROOT_PATH);
      }
      // Global beans defined here
  }
```

Update: After trying many different things, I found out after disabling my SchedulingConfigurer my app now starts. Here is my SchedulingConfigurer

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SchedulingProperties.class)
public class SchedulingConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    //Inject Runnables and properties

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());
        // call taskRegistrar.addFixedRateTask with runnable and property rate value
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        return taskScheduler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` implemented/extended by yourself? Although it is strange that the class is initialized before anything else (it isn't also a `WebApplicationInitializer` is it?). But I would ask the question if you really need it. Maybe you can post your customized class.

Comment: I don't implement it by itself. It's created by Spring Boot automagically. `DeletegatingWebMvcConfiguration` is a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. Doesn't that class get created from `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. I'll list the spring-boot dependencies from my pom file and the customized methods from my root configuration class.

Comment: It is but as you mentioned it explicitly I assumed you created one yourself.

Comment: I see a couple of (minor?) issues with your configuration. You are mixing spring versions (4.1.1 and 4.1.2) also (depending on which Spring Boot version you are using) it might be worse and adding 4.0.x versions into the mix. Next to that those dependencies are already part of the various starter projects you include. I would also suggest to add the `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` instead of including your own and remove the `@EnableSpringWebSupport` as that is part of Spring Boot. Why do you have a `@PropertySource` for loading the `application.properties` file, spring boot already does it.

Comment: When adding `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` you can remove the explicitly defined `spring-data-rest` and `spring-hateoas` dependencies and the `@EnableEntityLinks` annotation. Could you explain when you get this error (standalone or when deploying as a war). And please add which Spring Boot version you are using (if you are on 1.1 try at least the 1.1.9 release).

Comment: I added spring-boot-started-data-rest and bumped all the other spring dependencies to 4.0.8. I'm also using Spring Boot 1.1.8.RELEASE. I tried bumping it to 1.1.9 and I still get the same error. I also, removed the annotations as you suggested. I get this error when trying to run the application through IntelliJ by running the main method, so as standalone. Update: just tried running as a deployed war in tomcat and it works.

Comment: Update to the update: When I try executing the war as a standalone with embedded tomcat, I get that error.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this matters, but I excluded IntegrationAutoConfig with `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {IntegrationAutoConfiguration.class})` and the app starts up now. However, I get this when trying to send a message a `DirectChannel` `Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers` when trying to use my `IntegrationFlow`. My integration flow looks like `IntegrationFlows.from(new DirectChannel()).handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsTemplate()).destination("topic")).get();`

Comment: Would you mind sharing you app to play with it locally? Yes, if you use Spring Integration an `exclude` isn't for you. So, the issue is somewhere in the mix of concerns. We have several Spring Integration Boot applications with embedded Tomcat and they work well from IDEA. BTW, seems for me using Boot Maven plugin you can avoid versions for dependecnies. At least it works from Gradle.

Comment: What is the reason to duplicate the same annotated class `application.sources(ApplicationInitializer.class)` ?

Comment: I was hoping the error would be in my pom/ApplicationInitializer, so I copied both to a new project for testing in hopes that the error would be reproducible. However, it is not. I wonder if one of my other configuration classes is causing this error. If it matters, I have configuration classes for AbstractCassandraConfiguration, GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration, SchedulingConfigurer, SpringDataWebConfiguration, WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I also removed the application.sources code. I think it was needed for an early version of Spring Boot for a deployable WAR.

Comment: Update: I commented out my SchedulingConfigurer and now the application starts. I don't see anything out of the ordinary on my scheduling config. I'll post the code in the question.

Comment: Btw, if I comment out the taskScheduler() bean the application starts.

Comment: I guess it will work even, if you rename `taskScheduler` bean to something other. The Spring Integration uses the same name for its internal bean. I need to investigate the issue with SI + SchedulingConfigurer + taskScheduler bean. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Actually would great, if you'll minimize your app and share for us to catch the issue and try to fix it fot the future. Thanks

Comment: I've been having trouble reproducing the issue in a stripped down application. I changed the bean name of the taskScheduler as you suggested, and I got this error message `IllegalStateException: More than one TaskScheduler and/or ScheduledExecutorService  exist within the context. Remove all but one of the beans; or implement the SchedulingConfigurer interface and call ScheduledTaskRegistrar#setScheduler explicitly within the configureTasks() callback. Found the following beans: [taskScheduler, foo]`.

Comment: Also, I noticed that if I keep the `taskScheduler` bean name and remove all my `@Autowired` dependencies, then the application starts with even with the bean being defined. I'll keep trying to reproduce this in a stripped down application, but I've been unsuccessful so far.